# GADBannerView in collectionview doesnt receive click

Tags: ios, swift, admob

So i have a collectionview which contains a cell that appears every x amount of items that shows a adview. The ad gets added correctly the ad loads fine. However the view does not handle any clicks appropriately it seems as if the collectionview handles the touch and does not pass it through the underlying adview. The adview gets added dynamically maybe it has to do with that?

Comment: does your cell receive touches? does your cell is GADBannerViewDelegate?

Comment: The cell itself is not GADBannerViewDelegate. The delegate is in a different location

Comment: can you show your code? or link on your project?